# Difference between LocalRedirectPermanent vs RedirectPermanent in ASP.NET Core Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

What is the difference between LocalRedirectPermanent vs RedirectPermanent in ASP.NET Core Controller? When to use which one? 
I could not find some useful documentation regarding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`RedirectPermanent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.redirectpermanent?view=aspnetcore-3.1) produces a result that will redirect the browser/client to a given URL.

[`LocalRedirectPermanent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.localredirectpermanent?view=aspnetcore-3.1) produces the same result, but throws `InvalidOperationException` if the URL is not a local URL ([source](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Infrastructure/LocalRedirectResultExecutor.cs#L51-L54)):

> ```
> if (!urlHelper.IsLocalUrl(result.Url))
> {
>     throw new InvalidOperationException(Resources.UrlNotLocal);
> }
> ```

A local URL is one that begins with something like "/" or "~/". `LocalRedirectPermanent` is useful for *ensuring* returnUrl parameters are local to your web application, for example.